# Pytorch Geometric Graph Classification : AttributeError: 'Batch' object has no attribute 'local_var'

Tags: graph, pytorch

I am currently working on doing graph classification on the IMDB-Binary dataset using deep learning and specifically the pytorch geometric environment.

I have split my data into test/train samples that are list of tuples containing a graph and its label. One thing I've had to do is to treat the different graph as a "Batch", a large disconnected graph, using torch_geometric.data.Batch. To start, I am using a data loader with the following collate function

```
def collate(samples) :
  graphs,labels = map(list,zip(*samples))
  datalist = make_datalist(graphs)
  datalist = Batch.from_data_list(datalist)
  return datalist, torch.tensor(labels)
```

and my classifier is the following :

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dim, hidden_dim, n_classes):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GraphConv(in_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.conv2 = GraphConv(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.classify = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, n_classes)

    def forward(self, g):
        # Use node degree as the initial node feature. For undirected graphs, the in-degree
        # is the same as the out_degree.
        h = g.in_degrees
        # Perform graph convolution and activation function.
        h = F.relu(self.conv1(g, h))
        h = F.relu(self.conv2(g, h))
        g.ndata['h'] = h
        # Calculate graph representation by averaging all the node representations.
        hg = dgl.mean_nodes(g, 'h')
        return self.classify(hg)
```

Which simply averages the nodes representations of each graph, and feeds it to a MLP

The problem I come up with is that during the prediction of our batch, I have the error 
*AttributeError: 'Batch' object has no attribute 'local_var'*
and I can't find where it may come from, would anyone know ?

Thank you for taking the time to read !

Answer (score 0):

I am also experimenting with Pytorch geometric and its' data set capabilities.

Maybe following information will help someone in the future:

I'm facing AttributeErrors when forgetting to set @property annotated getters/setters for my data set class attributes. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#property

I think to answer your question we need more information about your `make_datalist` function.

However, here are the links to the batch class:

- https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/data.html
- https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/data/batch.html#Batch

And indeed, there is nothing like a `local_var` variable.